# Text frame aligned to grid not visible

Tags: adobe-indesign, layers, shapes, grids

I have an InDesign document with a 9x9 grid and a text frame that is aligned to it.

I don't know why, but I don't see the text frame unless I hover a mouse over it. I also tried to create a text frame on a second layer, but this doesn't help.

> This is how the page looks when I hover the mouse over the text frame:
>
> [image]

> And this is how it looks when I don't do it:
>
> [image]

How can I fix this? The text frame must remain visible without having to hover over it.

I use InDesign CS6. (Yes, quite old version.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the guides to the back.... Then guides will be covered up by page content.

[image]

There is *no way* to mix the front/back placement and have some guides in front and others in back. It's one or the other, you'll have to choose which works best for you.

[image]

<sub>(Although CS6 is older.. I *still* prefer it today... even though I have a CC subscription. There's no shame in using CS6 if it works for you.)</sub>

Comment: You can ? Hmm ok, I missed that one :)

Comment: You can @Lucian. I personally hate the guides in back.. but there is an option for it. `:)` I much prefer toggling guides.. you should edit a bit and leave that part...

Comment: Scott, out of curiosity, what are the reasons you prefer CS6 these days? And how do you deal with the inability to insert footnotes into tables?

Comment: @jsv I don't ever need footnotes in my work. So, that's a non-issue here. In general, I find the entire UI of the CC versions to be overly concerned with having smooth cursor movements as opposed to actually being precise. It "feels" like working in mud to me. The UI across the entire Adobe Suite was rewritten at CCv1. I feel to its detriment. Then, there's the entire *"pay us for a subscription or never access your copyrighted work"* aspect of the CC sales model I find distasteful. With CS6.... Adobe isn't locking me out of *any* of my work at any point - and I owe them not not one red ¢.

Comment: Just my opinion, I started my career with the original software versions and spent decades using them, The CC shift was noticeable to me in usability, in addition to attitude Adobe decided to take towards users. I'm not claiming others will, or should, feel like I do about it. I look at it a bit like cars... sure riding in a 2022 Mercedes can be a nice experience.. but me, I'd still rather be riding in a 1970 Mustang. They both do the same thing but the experience itself is just vastly different. And ... should you have to repair either.. well.. good luck with that computerized Mercedes.`:)`

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happens in the CC version, even with rectangles, not just text frames.

By default, InDesign display logic is made so it overlays guidelines on top of objects. Every single guideline sits above every single object, regardless of layers and this means, in your case, the text frame edges are hidden below document guidelines. If you create a black-filled rectangle, you will notice there is no way to move the rectangle above the guidelines.

You can use a shortcut to toggle guidelines on and off, which is achieved via <kbd>Command/CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> or by choosing `View > Guides & Grids > Hide/Show Guides` from the menu.

Or, change the default behavior via Preferences as @Scott mentioned.

[image]